# How to add regression line in ggplot wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have troubles adding linear regression lines to my ggplots.
This is how it should look like:
[image]

This is how it currently looks like:
[image]

This is my code:

```
p <- ggplot(data = wage, aes(x = educ, y = lwage, colour = black, 
                cex = IQ, pch = married, alpha = 0.7)) + geom_jitter() 

p1 <- p + facet_grid(urban~experclass) + geom_smooth(se=F,method="lm") 

p1 + labs(x = "Education (year)", y = "Log Wage", shape = "Marital status",
          colour = "Ethnicity") + guides(alpha = FALSE)
```

Is the position of my `geom_smooth` wrong? What I want is only one black regression line for each element of the plot - and not one by layer.

Furthermore what happens when I add a regression line is that the legend symbols change. Especially the IQ legend looks pretty weird. Is there something I did not consider here?

How it should look:

[image]

How it looks:

[image]

Comment: Can you try putting `group=interaction(urban, experclass)` into your aes?

Comment: I think even `group=1` would work in this case.

Comment: thx. That really worked! There is still a problem with the legend - I updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Try to add the argument `show_guide = FALSE` to the `geom_smooth` call.

Answer (score 0):

I can try to answer at least one part of your question - which is the part about plotting one regression line instead of two per panel. I don't have your data so I can't fully replicate your problem, but I think this will work.

The aesthetics in your original ggplot() call will be inherited by all the subsequent layers, including the geom_smooth. 
What you seem to want is the color aesthetic (which happens to be a grouping identifier) to apply only to the jittered points and not to the line. So you can write your code like this:

```
    p <- ggplot(data = wage, aes(x = educ, y = lwage, 
            cex = IQ, pch = married, alpha = 0.7)) + 
            geom_jitter() 

    p1 <- p + facet_grid(urban~experclass) + 
           geom_smooth(se=F,method="lm",
           aes(colour = black))
```

or, alternatively, as one single ggplot call in a modified style:

```
    p3 <- ggplot(data = wage, 
                 aes(x = educ, y = lwage, 
                  size = IQ, shape = married, alpha = 0.7)) + 
           geom_jitter() + 
           geom_smooth(se=F,method="lm",
                       aes(colour = black))+
           facet_grid(urban~experclass)
    p3
```